# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS crashes when changing keyboard to Japanese (Mozc)

Tags: 20.04

I tried to install the Japanese language and its input method, mozc. When I try to change the input method to mozc, the GUI sometimes crashes, but not always. Sometimes it crashes when adding the keyboard, and sometimes when changing the keyboard. However, when I added it early since installation, it did not crash. I cannot predict when it would crash, but I assume it is a problem with the input method.

I tried killing the X Window by `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`, fixing broken packages by entering recovery mode, and many of the solutions on the Internet for X Window crashes.

Edit: Provided more information.
I use GNOME(default for 20.04 LTS) for my desktop environment, and fcitx for my input method. I initially configured the language to Korean, and I tried to install Japanese and configure its input method. I used the Language Support app to add Japanese, and the Region&Language tab of the settings app to add Japanese keyboard.

I use Galaxy Book Ion from Samsung Electronics. The exact model number is NT950XCJ-X58L.

Comment: Very odd. What brand and model of computer are you using? I use the Japanese keyboard daily, so wonder if this is a hardware-specific case.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details. Which desktop environment? Which IM framework (i.e. IBus, Fcitx, something else)? How do you configure your input sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNOME developers have integrated IBus into the desktop environment, and since you are using standard Ubuntu with GNOME, and experience this problem, I would suggest that you use IBus instead of Fcitx.

So I would suggest that you:

- Change to IBus in *Language Support*
- Install `ibus-hangul` (for Korean) and `ibus-mozc` and `mozc-utils-gui` (for Japanese)
- Reboot
- Set your desired input sources in *Settings -> Region & Language*